# Can these pairs of regexes be simplified into one?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to fetch twitter usernames from strings. My current solution looks like this

```
def get_username(string):
    p1 = re.compile(r'twitter\.com/([a-z0-9_\.\-]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
    p2 = re.compile(r'twitter[\s\:@]+([a-z0-9_\.\-]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
    match1 = re.search(p1, string)
    match2 = re.search(p2, string)
    if match1:
        return match1.group(1)
    elif match2:
       return match2.group(1)
    else:
      return None
```

### Examples

```
get_username("Twitter: https://twitter.com/foo123")
get_username("Twitter: twitter.com/foo123")
get_username("https://twitter.com/foo123")
get_username("https://twitter.com/foo123?blah")
get_username("Twitter foo123")
get_username("Twitter @foo123")
get_username("Twitter: foo123")
get_username("Twitter: foo123 | youtube: ...")
```

I'm wondering if my two regexes can be simplified into one. My best attempt was

```
pattern = re.compile(r'twitter(?:(?:\.com/)|(?:[\s\:@]+))([a-z0-9_\.\-]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

but this fails on the first example because `Twitter: https` matches *before* `twitter.com/foo123`.

Comment: Maybe try *negative assertion (?<!:)*  to exclude the double matches?

Comment: Does it always end with the username ? that would be easier

Comment: @azro no. These usernames are inside a block of free text.

Comment: **UPDATE**: I've added some examples that make the existing answers wrong / outdated. Apologies to those people, as I didn't make my test cases robust from the beginning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add greedy quantifier `.*` to the following regex pattern `'.*twitter(?:(?:\.com/)|(?::?\s+@?))([a-z0-9_\.\-]+)'` to skip previous (optional) `twitter` keywords and catch the last one:

```
def get_username(string):
    pat = re.compile(r'.*twitter(?:(?:\.com/)|(?::?\s+@?))([a-z0-9_\.\-]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
    if (match := pat.search(string)):
        print(match.group(1))
        return match.group(1)
    return None

get_username("Twitter: https://twitter.com/foo123")
get_username("Twitter: twitter.com/foo123")
get_username("https://twitter.com/foo123")
get_username("https://twitter.com/foo123?blah")
get_username("Twitter foo123")
get_username("Twitter @foo123")
get_username("Twitter: foo123")
get_username("Twitter: foo123 | youtube: ...")
get_username("Twitt11er: foo123 | youtube: ...")
```

---

```
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
```

Answer (score 1):

If it always end with the username, just use `(\w+)$`

```
def get_username(string):
    if match1 := re.search(r'(\w+)$', string):
        return match1.group(1)
    return None
```

Comment: Unfortunately these items appear in a block of messy free text, so I can't make this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a negative lookahead of `(?!https?://)` to exclude all usernames which appear to start with `http://` or `https://`.

```
twitter(?:(?:\.com/)|(?:[\s\:@]+))(?!https?://)([a-z0-9_\.\-]+)
```

[Try on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dd1saP/1)

Comment: Good idea, but this fails `"Twitter: twitter.com/foo123"`

Answer (score 1):

If there can be multiple matches, you can use a negative lookahead to rule out twitter or `http://` or `https://` to the right, and get the capture group 1 value.

```
\btwitter(?:\.com/|(?!:?\s*(?:https?://|twitter\b)):?\s+@?)([\w.-]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\btwitter` Match the word twitter
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\.com/` Match `.com/`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!:?\s*(?:https?://|twitter\b))` Negative lookahead, assert not http:// or the word *twitter* preceded by an optional `:` and whitspace chars directly to the right of the current position
- `:?\s+@?)` Match an optional `:` 1+ whitspace chars and optional @
- `([\w.-]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ of the listed characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VeCVj5/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VaHtxT)

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\btwitter(?:\.com/|:?(?!\s*(?:https?://|twitter\b))\s+@?)([\w.-]+)", re.IGNORECASE)

def get_username(string):
    m = pattern.search(string)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    return None

print(get_username("Twitter: https://twitter.com/foo123"))
print(get_username("Twitter: twitter.com/foo123"))
print(get_username("https://twitter.com/foo123"))
print(get_username("https://twitter.com/foo123?blah"))
print(get_username("Twitter foo123"))
print(get_username("Twitter @foo123"))
print(get_username("Twitter: foo123"))
print(get_username("Twitter: foo123 | youtube: ..."))
```

Output

```
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
foo123
```